# php Laravel on apache sever got an error in mac platform

Tags: php, macos, laravel, apache, xampp

after run the server, I went to `localhost/wedservice/public`
  got an error blow ....

> The stream or file "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/wedservice/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied

`php version 7.1.7`

Comment: looks like you need to make that particular file writeable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the terminal and go to your folder `htdocs/wedservice/storage` and grant permission to write and read, with the `chmod` command:

```
chmod -R 777 storage
```

Comment: how to give permission without command means doing manually ?@Jose Rojas

Comment: @kobi other way is by right click on the folder go to information, at the bottom of the window you can see the users and permissions, there you can modify them

Comment: Thn So much @Jose Rojas